# AJAX - retrieve more than one response value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have AJAX code that returns a string of HTML to append to what's currently in a div.

I now also want it to return a value to update a hidden field, HiddenFieldSortLetter so that can be used for future AJAX calls.

I could add:

```
ByRef varAJAXHiddenFieldSortLetterNew As String
```

at the end of the parameters for

```
Public Shared Function fGetData
```

but then how could I change

```
success: function (msg) { $("#<%=dvGridItems01.ClientID%>").append(msg.d); },
```

so that it also updates the hidden field HiddenFieldSortLetter ?

```
        $.ajax(
        { type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/fGetData", 
        data: varData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",
        success: function (msg) { $("#<%=dvGridItems01.ClientID%>").append(msg.d); }, 
        Error: function (x, e) { alert("Network error"); } });
```

ASP.NET 3.5 VB.NET:

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function fGetData(ByVal pageIndex As Integer, _
                                    ByVal isSearch As Integer, _
                                    ByVal searchText As String, _
                                    ByVal varAJAXHiddenFieldConsumerID As Object, _
                                    ByVal varAJAXHiddenFieldSortLetter As Object _
                                    ) As String

        Dim strReturn As String = ""

        Dim c1 As New cVDisplayGridItems
        With c1
            .pConsumerID = varAJAXHiddenFieldConsumerID
            .pAJAXSortLetter = varAJAXHiddenFieldSortLetter

            If isSearch = 1 Then
                'Search results
                .pSearchTerm = searchText.Trim
                .fGenerateHTMLForSearch()
            Else
            End If

            strReturn = .pHTML

        End With

        Return strReturn

    End Function
```

Comment: What you you mean, you have a String? Why `msg.d`? Is `msg` not an Object?

Comment: @PHPglue fGetData() As String in the VB.NET code returns a string.

Comment: I don't know asp. A String has no property `d`.

Comment: You would encode two values into your response

Comment: the `.d` is an ASP.NET thing with at least some types of "AJAX" - i.e. WCF JSON response always like `{d: { __type: "some string", restOfesponseObject }}`

Comment: Does your code work as is before you add the second value?

Comment: @Bindrid yes it has been working for a number of months, though the sample code I pasted had a whole lot of 'company confidential' fields and a few bits of other information stripped out. Hopefully I did that carefully enough not to confuse or break the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the server side I created a struct to hold the two values that I want to return at once. I serialized that and returned it.

```
   Public Structure dataResponse
    Dim  pHTML as String
    Dim  hidden as String
end Structure
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function fGetData(ByVal pageIndex As Integer, _
                                ByVal isSearch As Integer, _
                                ByVal searchText As String, _
                                ByVal varAJAXHiddenFieldConsumerID As Object, _
                                ByVal varAJAXHiddenFieldSortLetter As Object _
                                ) As String

    Dim strReturn As String = ""

    Dim c1 As New cVDisplayGridItems
    With c1
        .pConsumerID = varAJAXHiddenFieldConsumerID
        .pAJAXSortLetter = varAJAXHiddenFieldSortLetter

        If isSearch = 1 Then
            'Search results
            .pSearchTerm = searchText.Trim
            .fGenerateHTMLForSearch()
        Else
        End If

        strReturn = .pHTML

    End With
    Dim retStruct as new dataResponse()
    retStruct.pHTML = strReturn
    retStruct.hidden = somefunctionthatgetsthehidden()
      System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer ser = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();


    Return ser.Serialize(retStruct)
End Function
```

Then on the client I changed the success: to look like this...(if you set ClientIdMode on the control to Static, you don't have to use the <%= stuff.

```
success: function (msg) {
    var myRes = JSON.parse(msg.d);
    $("#dvGridItems01").append(myRes.pHTML);
    $("#hdnTextBox").val(myRes.hidden);

 },
```

Comment: Not proofed but you get the idea

Comment: yes that is very helpful thanks. I can have a go at implementing it over the next few days. Thanks again.